# Who first noticed that the radiation pressure formula $p=U/c$ agreed with $E=pc$ from special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, history

Does anyone know behind stories?
As it seems that $p=\frac Uc$ was known before the advent of special theory of relativity, (Halliday, Resnick, Walker says that Maxwell derived this.) when $E=pc$ was first derived by plugging in $m=0$ for $E^2=m^2 c^4 +p^2 c^2$, were physicists happy that the two formulas agreed? Who first noticed this agreement? What was the reaction? And, who derived $E=pc$ from the special theory of relativity point of view? I know that $p=\gamma m v$ was first derived by Planck, but I do not know much anything else such as who derived $E^2=m^2 c^4+p^2 c^2$ and who first plugged in $m=0$.

Comment: Einstein already knew of this relationship when he developed this formula.

Comment: The guidelines at https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-history-of-physics-questions-be-on-topic suggest that this of probably be migrated to [hsm.se] .